# How to make the entire TouchableOpacity clickable while has other components inside?

Tags: react-native

I have a component that is basically a TouchableOpacity with a few TextInputs wrapped inside.

It has two states: expanded and unExpanded. When it's unExpanded, the TextInputs are disabled, and by clicking the TouchableOpacity it transits to the expanded state, where TouchableOpacity is disabled and TextInputs are editable.

However, the disabled TextInputs are taking away the clicks. TouchableOpacity is only clickable in the empty space. How can I make the entire TouchableOpacity to be clickable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a prop in react-native that controls whether or not a `View` can be the target of touch events. Give your disabled `TextInput`'s `pointerEvents={'none'}` prop like this;

```
<TextInput pointerEvents={'none'} />
```